# Phonegap hybrid app | Webview

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I have downloaded PhoneGap, the problem is:
When I'm trying to load a webview like in java, and it keeps opening a browser.
I want it to open the web on the same browser of the app , How do I make such a thing ?

I have tried editing the config.xml file with the following

```
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />
```

Still, it makes a jump into a web browser. really weird.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090218/open-url-in-webview-phonegap/35132022#35132022

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to open a Web URL at the same instance of your App? If thats the case, do not do it. It will just broke your application because a lot of elements from cordova will just have strange behavior, like **BackButton or onDeviceReady.**

If you want to open content from a website inside your App, use other ways, like iframes/RSS feeds or even HTML analysis (check page HTML content and filter any relevant information).

But, if you want to open it anyways, **do the following:**

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

Hope it helps. Best regards!